# VSCode complains in launch.json about "Configured debug type 'cppvsdbg' is installed but not supported in this environment."

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, launch

I'm trying to run a C program in VSCode. I am working to get a valid launch.json file, but it's complaining about the `"type": "cppvsdbg"` line, saying that the "Configured debug type 'cppvsdbg' is installed but not supported in this environment."

I tried starting fresh and debugging according to the VSCode website, but they have me using a `"type": "cppdbg"` option, which won't work for me because it disallows newer options like `"console"`. I also tried searching for keywords in this error, but could only find similar posts using different languages (mostly Python). So here we are!

I'm running a mac, OS Monterey 12.6, on an M1 Max chip. My VSCode version is up-to-date, "1.71.0 (Universal)".